# Attempting to factor $(x^2)+5x=0$ via the grouping method.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, factoring

Now, I am perfectly aware that I can easily factor this by taking out the common factor, so  I would get $x(x+5)$. This way the roots of my equation would be $0$ and $-5$
What is confusing me is that, even though it is a longer and a redundant way, the grouping method should work. I am referring to the quadratic equation in the form of *$(ax^2)+bx+c$* there should be factors *ac* which has a sum equal to *$b$*. Of course, I can also re-write the original equation as *$(x^2)+5x+0$* since my c would equal to $0$ in this case.
Now, I need to find two numbers that add up to 5 that have a product of $0.$ It is obvious that these numbers are $0$ and $5.$ But doesn't this indicate that the factored form should be $x(x-5)=0$?

I think I made a mistake somehwere, I just can't figure out where...

Comment: $$
\begin{align}
x^2+5x & = x^2 + 5x -0x - 0 \\ {} \\
& = x(x+5) - 0(x+5) \\ {} \\
& = (x-0)(x+5)
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The roots $r_1$ and $r_2$ of $x^2+\alpha x+\beta$ are such that $r_1r_2=\beta$ and that $r_1+r_2=\color{red}{\mathbf-}\alpha$. So, you're after two numbers with product $0$ and sum $-5$; these are $0$ and $-5$.

Comment: Can you please explain why? According to here - https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/x2f8bb11595b61c86:quadratics-multiplying-factoring/x2f8bb11595b61c86:factor-quadratics-strategy/a/factoring-quadratics-in-any-form the sum of those 2 numbers should be equal to b, not negative b. And I have probably solved a hundred or so equations with this method...

Comment: According to that page, if you want to factor $x^2+\alpha x+\beta$, you find to numbers $x_1$ and $x_2$ whose sum is $\alpha$ and whose product is $\beta$; then $x^2+\alpha x+\beta=(x+x_1)(x+x_2)$. So, since $0+5=5$ and $0\times5=0$, $x^2+5x=x(x+5)$. But then the roots of $x^2+\alpha x+\beta$ are $-x_1$ and $-x_2$.

Comment: Ah, now I get it. It is a(x-x1)(x-x2) when dealing with the roots of the equation, but when using the grouping method (since the a and b we get via the grouping method would be the opposite of the roots?) those negative signs should be positive instead, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is crystal clear now.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

Only your last statement is wrong. You're right that if you want to use the grouping method (also called splitting the middle term, the AC method, and possibly other names) the numbers should be $5$ and $0$. But remember, from there you split the linear term and get
$$x^2+5x+0x+0=x(x+5)+0(x+5)=(x+0)(x+5)=x(x+5)$$
However, as you said your first method is easier in this case.

Comment: I seem to have understood it now. Those 2 numbers we get from the grouping method always tend to be the opposite of an equation's root. So, when we use an equation's root to factor it, we should subtract but when using the numbers we got from the grouping method, add them instead. Did I get it right?

Comment: @EvilRaceHorse Sounds like you understand it. The grouping method will get you the factorization, and from there the roots are easy to see. If $(x+5)$ is one of the factors, then $-5$ is a root and vice versa.

Comment: But can we categorically say that the two numbers we get from the grouping method are always the roots of the equation but with opposite signs? It also seems that this method doesn't work on when x^2 has a coefficient other than 1?

I mean, so far finding those two number from the grouping method immediately lets me find out the roots and how to factor it. But with this example: 4x^2+4x+1 the two numbers I get from the grouping method (2 and 2) are totally different from the root, which is -0.5. I guess those 2 numbers from the grouping method are only opposite of the roots when (b^2-4ac)>0?

Comment: @EvilRaceHorse I don't view the result of the grouping method as numbers, but rather a factorization. Sure, along the way you'll get the numbers $2$ and $2$, but those aren't what you're really after. The next step is to split the first degree term and continue: $4x^2+4x+1=4x^2+2x+2x+1=2x(2x+1)+1(2x+1)=(2x+1)(2x+1)=(2x+1)^2$.

Comment: So briefly, no, the intermediate numbers you get don't have to be the actual roots (or their negatives).

Comment: Just with brief experimentation, I noticed that if x^2 has no coefficient, then those intermediate numbers tend to be the opposite of the actual roots. But when x^2 does have a coefficient, then the roots are the opposite of those intermediate numbers but also divided by that coefficient. For example, here: 3x^2+11x-4 those intermediate numbers are -1, 12. But the roots are those numbers with opposite signs (1, -12) divided by 3. So, the final result for the roots is 1/3, -4.
I think they definitely have a non-random relationship here.

Comment: @EvilRaceHorse Yep, not random at all. In your latest example, we split it into $3x^2+12x-x-4$ and then factor the leading coefficient, getting $3(x^2+4x-(1/3)x-4/3)$. Note that since $12\times (-1)=-12$ (our reason for using the numbers $12,-1$ in the first place), we have $4\times (-1/3)=-4/3$, so the split middle term still satisfies the conditions for factoring by grouping and now we have a polynomial in parentheses with leading coefficient $1$. As you discovered, in this case it's easy to see the roots from the intermediate step.

Comment: Now I wonder if this would also work for quadratic equations where the x^2 term cannot be factored out...

Answer (score 1):

$ax^2 + bx + c = x^2 + 5x + 0 = 0.$

This will have roots

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{2a}\left[-b \pm\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}\right].$

This equals

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\left[-5 \pm\sqrt{25}\right].$

This simplifies to the two roots of

$\left[\frac{1}{2} \times 0\right]$ and $\left[\frac{1}{2} \times -10\right].$

Comment: Thank you, but I wasn't really after the roots of the equation but more about a specific way to get to the roots where I had a little confusion. The answer above by José Carlos Santos explains it really well.

Comment: @EvilRaceHorse The procedure that I showed indicates how to use the formula $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2a}\left[-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}\right].$  Jose Carlos Santos' approach focuses on using [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) which will often take you longer than immediately using the formula that I specified.  It will depend on the specific values for $a,b$ and $c$ in the equation $ax^2 + bx + c = 0.$

Comment: You are right, if I had to just find the roots, that would be the method I would go rather than Vieta's theorem, but that is probably because of using that formula for years in high school.